react: imports not working in another file not working
what may be the cause of these imports not working in my react app?
index.jsx
import { 
  getData,
  getOne,
} from "../../../server/config/db.js";
import * as mysql from "mysql2";


db.js snippet

export async function getData() {
  const [rows] = await pool.query(`
  SELECT * FROM claim`);
  return rows;
}

export async function getOne(id) {
  const [rows] = await pool.query(`
  SELECT * 
  FROM claim
  WHERE id = ?
  `, [id]);

  return rows[0];
}

the import works form server/index.js
expecting to access the exported functions from the index.jsx file

you are trying to access server side code directly into client side. you cannot execute it, instead you should create a server side api and execute the code there.
